# Load Test - Error - Could not read result repository: Unknown request id in results:185

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing

I have setup a load test rig with a Client (VS 2013 Update 5), Test Controller and 5 Test Agents. For testing the working of this environment, I have configured load test to run just for 5 users (Step based).

At the end of load test, the Visual Studio is displaying the error message

> "Could not read result repository: Unknown request id in results:185"

I have checked if the agents are running out of CPU, RAM etc. Even I have enabled logs on Test Controller, Agents but found no clue or error message.

However I found that the error is occurring due to missing records in the table `WebLoadTestRequestMap` of LoadTest2010 database.

I have set the value `none` to the option `Timing Details Storage` and found that this issue is not occurring. When I set this value to `All Individual Details`, the error is occurring again.

I don't know what's causing this error. Can anyone help me fixing this error?

Comment: There is another discussion of the same problem at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fe459cbb-331e-4dc2-bda1-73e3abcc8604/load-test-error-could-not-read-result-repository-unknown-request-id-in-results185?forum=vstest

Comment: Hi Adrian, the particular discussion in MSDN is posted by myself only. As I did not find a solution there, I posted the error in here also.